# Dynamic change text with different Definition

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I must print my `PDF` file often with 2 options: A or B.

When I change contents of file, it's often error-prone when so much positions in document must be changed.

Now I want use dynamic change:

example some text definition:

**Definition in Option A:**

vartitleA.1 = This is option A

vartitleA.2 = Option A: ABCDE

vartitleA.3 = Display option A

**Definition in Option B:**

vartitleB.1 = No A, only B

vartitleB.2 = Option B: GHJK1238

vartitleB.3 = Display option B - No A

and in code when I select the option = B, then the `.pdf` file should display all definition of option B in all positions of vartitle1, 2, 3

My minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%Need definition text of option A & B
% vartitleA.1 = This is option A
% vartitleA.2 = Option A: ABCDE
% vartitleA.3 = Display option A
%...similar for option B

\begin{document}

%here can i set ex. select option = option A and automatic set vartitle1=vartitleA.1, vartitle2 = vartitleA.2, vartitle3 = vartitleA.3...
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is option A %\vartitle1
\tcblower
Option A: ABCDE %\vartitle2
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title = {Display option A}] %vartitle3 
This is option A %\vartitle1
\tcblower
Option A: ABCDE %\vartitle2
\end{tcolorbox}

Display option A %\vartitle3 

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question is totally confusing. Which option? There is no option apart from the `tcolorbox` title. What is the dynamic change?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer; thank so much, i just some updated, may be better understanding

Comment: Either I am totally stupid or ....  No, it has not been clarified for me...  `%here can i set ex. select option = option A` is not really useful for -- what is option A? How should we test for option A?

Comment: Sorry, i don' know how i can definite variable and text display of option A, B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defined six macros, 3 each for the `\variantA...` and `\variantB...` titles and an `\ifoptionA` macro, that is toggled with `\SelectOption`, which an be specified as `A` or anything else, which corresponds to `B` then.

The toggling defines `\localtitle...` which are displayed in the `tcolorbox` instances.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%Need definition text of option A & B
% vartitleA.1 = This is option A
% vartitleA.2 = Option A: ABCDE
% vartitleA.3 = Display option A
%...similar for option B

\newif\ifoptionA

\newcommand{\vartitleAone}{This is option A}
\newcommand{\vartitleAtwo}{option ABCDE}
\newcommand{\vartitleAthree}{Display option A}

\newcommand{\vartitleBone}{No A,only B}
\newcommand{\vartitleBtwo}{option B: GHJK1238}
\newcommand{\vartitleBthree}{Display option B - No A}


\def\localtitleone{}
\def\localtitletwo{}
\def\localtitlethree{}


\newcommand{\SelectOption}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{A}{%
    \global\optionAtrue
  }{%
    \global\optionAfalse
  }%
  \ifoptionA
  \gdef\localtitleone{\vartitleAone}
  \gdef\localtitletwo{\vartitleAtwo}
  \gdef\localtitlethree{\vartitleAthree}
  \else
  \gdef\localtitleone{\vartitleBone}
  \gdef\localtitletwo{\vartitleBtwo}
  \gdef\localtitlethree{\vartitleBthree}
  \fi
}


\newtcolorbox{mynicebox}[1][]{%
  #1%
}


\begin{document}

\SelectOption{A}

\begin{mynicebox}
  \localtitleone
  \tcblower
  \localtitletwo
\end{mynicebox}

\begin{mynicebox}[title={\localtitlethree}]
  \localtitleone
  \tcblower
\localtitletwo
\end{mynicebox}


Display option A %\vartitleA.3 


\SelectOption{B}

\begin{mynicebox}
  \localtitleone
  \tcblower
  \localtitletwo
\end{mynicebox}

\begin{mynicebox}[title={\localtitlethree}]
  \localtitleone
  \tcblower
\localtitletwo
\end{mynicebox}



\end{document}
```

Comment: brillant, your above code that i you truly want. Many thank

Comment: +1 for displaying telepathy and divination skills! :-)

Comment: @Mico: Yes, I will get a badge for this ;-)

Comment: This site should definitely provide a GOLD badge for such a skill!! 

Comment: @Mico: Go ahead to Meta.SE and propose such badge times. And of course, for me, it must be a new category: Platinum ;-)